# Insert Sharepoint Credentials using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, ms-word, windows-security

When trying to open or sometimes close, via powershell, a word document in a sharepoint directory hosted in my company's network, the windows security box popup.
How can I authenticate this ? Here is part of my script:

```
$docpath = "\\sharepoint.[Domain].com\[...]\mydoc.docx"
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("$docpath")
{...process...}
$doc.Close([ref]$true)
$word.Quit()
$word = $null
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

[Here is a visual example of what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp75Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found something that works, but only if if have an admin user. Still would like to know if there is a way to do this without this kind of permission.
Here is the code:

```
$User = "domain\useradmin"
$Cred = Get-Credential -Credential $User
$srv = "sharepoint.[Domain].com"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $srv -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock{

$docpath = "\\sharepoint.[Domain].com\[...]\mydoc.docx"
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("$docpath")
{...process...}
$doc.Close([ref]$true)
$word.Quit()
$word = $null 

 }
```